# CSS - aligning wrapped floating divs to the center

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to create something like a gallery that shows different number of images per row based on the width of the browser. This has already been achieved using `overflow: hidden` in the outer div and `float: left` in the inner div.

However, what happens with this is that my images are always aligned to the left, leaving alot of whitespace on the right. How do I make it such that the gallery is always centered in the screen no matter how many images there are per row.

My code is on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzqAs

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: There is nothing here, Monsieur. My giant magnifying glass on a stick tells no lies.

Comment: @mohkhan apologies for formatting the link incorrectly. it's working now.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Asqwz

Comment: So, did something work for ya?

Comment: @mtashev unfortunately not yet. I am now trying to get my example to work. :(

Comment: Did you try out our solutions? Where does it fail this time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: http://codepen.io/anon/full/mtBbF

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="red box">red</div>
  <div class="blue box">blue</div>
  <div class="black box">black</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  text-align:center; /*You would need to define this in a parent of .container*/
}
.container{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. but I am still trying to get it to fit into my existing code. Does it make a difference if my `class="box"` was actually applied to a `table` instead of a `div`? and is specifying the `width` and `height` of the div essential too?

Comment: Well, tables are much more difficult to work with in CSS, may I ask why are you needing them?. For the element dimensions, I don't think it is necessary to set them explicitly, but you should've noted this differences in your codepen so I could've accommodated them in my solution

Comment: because each "image" in my gallery is currently made up of a table that has one row and two columns. the first column shows the actual image while the second column shows some details and has some buttons in it.

Comment: I would advise against using tables for styling/positioning purposes, maybe we can come up with a way to position your elements using divs and then apply this solution. How about you start by making a codepen with a sample of your actual markup and we'll see if we can figure it out

Comment: Have put up my humble table at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzqAs . Pardon me for the not-very-clean code, I am really quite new at CSS. :(

Comment: Are the dimensions for the images and boxes fixed and constant or do you need to accommodate for variations in height or something?

Comment: the images may change sizes (sometimes portrait sometimes landscape). Thank you so much for willing to help I genuinely appreciate it. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34276/discussion-between-koala-dev-and-user1258600)

Answer (score 0):

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/bfddJ/)

You need to use an id(or class) on the main div. Set `width: 300+px and margin: auto`
Also your boxes should be with `display: inline-block` to allow them to begave "inline"
I have changed colors of the boxes a bit for better visibility.

Comment: hi. yeah I did try this out but it doesnt seem to be what I want. I require the boxes to flow to the next line automatically when the browser width is too short. So in your demonstration "orange" should move to the next line automatically.

Comment: Change the width to 300 and see that "orange" goes on the next line.